# Missing revisions after "git svn clone"

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

After running:

```
git svn clone https://svn.mycompany.eu/project/trunk
```

There are some missing revisions (for exemaple 500 from 4700 of total revisions). It's a problem, because we have joined a number of commits with a number of tasks in Trac. Can anybody help, please?

Comment: Is it the same if you do `git svn clone --stdlayout`?

Comment: It's likely those commits exist in a different branch than `trunk`

Answer (score 2):

You cloned the trunk only, so git-svn didn't detect any branches.  Try:

```
git svn clone -s https://svn.mycompany.eu/project
```

Odds are that's where those missing revisions are.  If your project does not adhere to SVN conventions, you will need to tell git svn where to find those branches.